# How can the code be modified so that multiple images can be read and stored in an array? so that they will be used for LSB steganography

Tags: python-3.x, steganography

The problem here is that this is only used for one image and i need to optimize it so that multiple images can be stored. (their width,height etc)

I am not fluent in python. I have worked on it about 4 years ago but now i have almost forgotten most part of the syntax.

```
def __init__(self, im):
    self.image = im
    self.height, self.width, self.nbchannels = im.shape
    self.size = self.width * self.height

    self.maskONEValues = [1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128]
    #Mask used to put one ex:1->00000001, 2->00000010 .. associated with OR bitwise
    self.maskONE = self.maskONEValues.pop(0) #Will be used to do bitwise operations

    self.maskZEROValues = [254,253,251,247,239,223,191,127]
    #Mak used to put zero ex:254->11111110, 253->11111101 .. associated with AND bitwise
    self.maskZERO = self.maskZEROValues.pop(0)

    self.curwidth = 0  # Current width position
    self.curheight = 0 # Current height position
    self.curchan = 0   # Current channel position
```

I want to store multiple images (their width, height etc) from a file path (that contains these images) in an array

Comment: Can you describe the data that you want to store in your array

Comment: The height, width and the channels pixels of each image

Comment: By channel pixel,  do you mean individual channels that compose an image (ex. RGB)

Comment: Yes exactly that

Comment: is extension of image files same or variable? If it is same,  then can you tell what is the extension

Comment: The extension is always .PNG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TRY:-**

```
from PIL import Image
import os

# This variable will store the data of the images
Image_data = []

dir_path = r"C:\Users\vasudeos\Pictures"

for file in os.listdir(dir_path):

    if file.lower().endswith(".png"):

        # Creating the image file object
        img = Image.open(os.path.join(dir_path, file))

        # Getting Dimensions of the image
        x, y = img.size
        # Getting channels of the image
        channel = img.mode

        img.close()

        # Adding the data of the image file to our list
        Image_data.append(tuple([channel, (x, y)]))


print(Image_data)
```

Just change the `dir_path` variable with the directory of your Image files. This code stores the color channel and dimensions of the Images, in a separate tuple  unique to that file. And adds the tuple to a list.

**P.S.:**
**Tuple format = (channels, dimensions)**

Comment: I am re-evaluating the code and i am not seeing the maskONEValues and maskZEROValues. are they not useful for the code?

Comment: what is being stored by mask1 and mask0 ?

Comment: I would suggest you to first try out my code, see if it works for you. And then we can work on improvements or optimisation of it

Comment: The difference between the two codes, is that I made a use of more functions provided by the `PIL` library, in order to reduce the pain for me to code everything. On the other hand, you seemed to have created a class in order to achieve the same results. Secondly since you have provided just a snippet of your code rather then the full version, so it's hard for me to calibrate/understand the logic that you have used in your code.

Comment: Here is the full code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56314888/optimizing-a-code-so-that-it-can-hide-multiple-images-using-lsb-steganography

Comment: The code is for **LSB steganography**, but this question had different motives then that,  It wouldn't be legit for me to give answer to a different question here, So I would recommend you to either delete this question or mark any given answer as  correct if that helped you. So that viewers of this post can move on to your further query then just trying to fix this one ^_^.